# Can't connect to jupyterlab: 404 Client error (/lab)

Tags: google-dl-platform

I have deployed VM Machine and increased Quotas on Google Cloud Platform and they approved it. However, when I connect the VM machine using SSH command (gcloud compute ssh --project ammi-project-283319 --zone us-east1-b pytorch-2-vm -- -L 8080:localhost:8080) in the terminal and then launch **jupyter lab**, I am having the following error:

> **404 Client error (/lab)**

Comment: Possible workaround: google has jupyterlab notebook already installed and available to you (see [AI Platform Notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-notebooks)). The good part for me is you can launch a notebook without GPU just to code and relaunch it with GPU when you want to train or do inference.

Comment: @Iñigo still I can not use AI Platform Notebook either when I start the VM machine the Open jupyterlab button does not show up even though I stay connected for long.